# Angular logical expression does not update when scope changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Why does angular logical expression does not update the value when the scope inside changes?

I have a directive `ng-show` that shows a div when a logic is true:

```
<div ng-show="!employee.name && !employee.job"></div>
```

say for example:

```
$scope.employee.name = true;
$scope.employee.job = false;
```

would hide the div (!employee.name && !employee.job == false). But when we dynamically change the employee using angular `$http`:

```
$http.get('/api/job').
success(function(data) {
    $scope.employee.name = data.name; // false
    $scope.employee.job = data.job; // false
}); // !employee.name && !employee.job == true
```

the logic value in the view does not change:

```
<td><% employee.name %></td> <!-- false-->
<td><% employee.job %></td> <!-- false-->
<!-- !false && !false == true -->
<td><% !employee.name && !employee.job %></td> <!-- STILL FALSE -->
<!-- funny thing is no error occurred -->
```

thats why the div does **NOT** show on success `$http request` because logic does **NOT** get updated?

```
<div ng-show="!employee.name && !employee.job"></div> <!-- does not show -->
```

Comment: your logic is backwards, would only show if both are false

Comment: typo error wait

Comment: Create a demo that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check your value if below example if change like

```
var emp= {
 name:undefined,
  job:false
 }
```

then  `ng-show` remain in previous state

```js
var app = angular.module("myapp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", ['$scope', function($scope) {
  
  var emp= {
  name:false,
  job:false
  }
   
  
  $scope.employee = emp;

  
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myapp">  
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">    
  Name: {{employee.name}}   <br/>
    Job: {{employee.job}}   <br/>
    <br/>
    Condition Status : {{!employee.name && !employee.job}}
    
    <div ng-show="!employee.name && !employee.job">
      <h1>Div </h1>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: because $scope.employee.name &   $scope.employee.job  gets undefined value refer @Harish Kommuri solution

Comment: hey guys i found out whats wrong, turns out `employee.job == true` because it is stored as string there `for employee.job = "false" == true` how do i make "false" = false as in boolean false?